# Blurred text in Chrome when CSS animations are applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have a problem with the animated text on my website. I am using the following CSS to do the animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRightBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInRightBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(2000px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInRightBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(2000px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInRightBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(2000px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.fadeInRightBig {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRightBig;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInRightBig;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInRightBig;
    animation-name: fadeInRightBig;
}
```

When .fadeInRightBig is applied to a text element it becomes blurry in Chrome as seen in the following picture. The first element has not the animation applied. Maybe it is a little hard to see due to the resizing of the image.

[image: Blurred text in Chrome]

As far as i know this problem only exists in Chrome. In Firefox and IE the animated text is crisp.

I have tried to recreate the problem in a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2608/). However in this Fiddle it does not seem to be a problem.

My website is located here: http://steffanlildholdt.dk/.

Anyone having idea to what the problem can be?

Comment: Looks fine for me in latest Chrome 39. Aside: use `body { overflow-y: scroll }` to prevent the jumpy look caused by the scrollbar appearing when expanding those boxes.

Comment: I am also using Chrome 39 and I see a clear difference between Chrome and Firefox. The website is normally longer so the scrollbar will be present at all times. I have just removed the areas that are not affected by this problem ;)

Comment: I dunno if being on Mac is a difference - [Here is your site in Chrome and Firefox side by side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/scX5m.png)

Comment: Yeah it seems to be fine. Then I guess a Mac must render the website differently and the problem is only on PCs (Windows)

Answer (score 1):

On the elements that appear blurred, apply the following styles:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I have tried to add these lines but it seems that this fix only makes the non-animated text as blurry as the animated text. :( (http://bit.ly/1DvOHFT.)